# Wifi will not automatically connect after Ubuntu update

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, suspend, broadcom

Today I updated from `Ubuntu 18.04.something LTS` to `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`. My laptop no longer automatically connects to Wifi (hidden network), it worked "fine" before updating. Each time I turn on my computer or resume from sleep I have to go to Settings, then WiFi and click "Connect to Hidden Network…". To make things worse, after manually connecting, if I click on the cog icon next to my network on the available networks list, Settings window freezes completely, and I have to restart the computer in order to make the window disappear. Any idea how to auto-connect, like before the update?

Comment: Have you tried removing the saved wifi and then re-adding it after you upgraded?

Comment: Yes, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the correct wireless drivers fixes the problem. Follow the instructions from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers?answertab=votes#tab-top) post (for Broadcom wifi cards).